very large .iso file, add small number of files quickly
In windows 11, NTFS file system hdd or ssd,
Suppose that there is a very large .iso file, for example 200 GB.
That .iso file contains only data files (like music, text, documents..) and not bootable.
And I want to add some small number of files to that large .iso,
without extracting it or re-compressing it.
So that
it takes very little time,
no large free disk space is required.

To modify and already “.iso-ed” .iso typically requires rearranging much of the file system. Because .isos are in such a complicated structure (to be used as an OS,) they need very specific orders, and throwing a few random files here and there, even if small, probably will mess up that specific order.

What you want isn’t possible, even if you were to open the entire ISO in memory like an archive, you would still have to create a new copy before the new file replaced the original file.

Actually, I saw potential in this program (https://github.com/ajkhoury/partcopy) and asked the question. For me it seems that lack of RAM size is not the fundamental reason that makes this problem impossible.

If .iso has a complex structure, then it seems to be clear evidence that the answer is impossible.

Are you talking about an ISO9660 filesystem? I'm asking because people tend to call any raw image "iso". ISO13490 allows adding files to ISO9660 on a CD-R. Mount options session= and sbsector= in Linux make me suspect that maybe we can take a raw image of ISO9660, add data to the end and get a mountable ISO13490. I'm not sure, I cannot do this even in Linux, I don't know Windows in this matter at all. Anyway, in principle maybe this is possible.

@KamilMaciorowski Windows-mountable ISO files are ISO-9660 with some extensions for more file types/properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/imapi/disc-formats), but don't seem to officially get the append features of 13490. Maybe some 3rd-party software could edit the files, but not sure if they'd still be mountable

@Kamil, yes it's easy to append to an ISO-13490 image, and I've certainly done that (long ago, with cdrecord and mkisofs, I think).  And an ISO-13490 filesystem is valid ISO-9660.

Unfortunately, adding files to a .ISO file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) always requires recreating the entire file.
They are optimized for a physical CD or other optical storage, with sequential access and no wasted space. Adding any files requires adding some bytes at the beginning of the .ISO where it describes each file's location. This means all the other existing files have to get "pushed" about that many bytes further as well, meaning the entire thing gets re-written. It's the same for removing any files too - proper .ISO files don't have any empty space, so it's not as simple as just removing that data.
More modern disk image formats like VHD or VMDK are not sequential and can be edited more directly (but are terrible to use with CDs).

In theory, recreating wouldn't be necessary, in terms of having a second copy exist before you can delete the first one.  Pushing every file later can be done by copying in-place to open up the gap you need, by a program that opens the file read+write and extends its length a bit.  Then memory-map it and memmove, or do the equivalent thing reading a chunk near the end, writing it 4K later, etc. until you're close to the start.

Actually, some Linux filesystems let you open up holes in files without rewriting all the bytes.  Since the OP is talking about a .iso file stores on a filesystem, if they hadn't specified NTFS + Windows, it would be possible for an ISO-grower to use Linux fallocate(FALLOC_FL_INSERT_RANGE) on an XFS or ext4 filesystem (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) to make the file a multiple of 4K longer with the hole appearing at your choice of offset instead of just at the end like if you'd done ftruncate to set the length.  So then you'd only need to rewrite the metadata.

It's certainly possible to amend to an ISO-9660 image, but only if it was created with that in mind as a multi-session filesystem.  I have no idea which Windows tools support multi-session CD or UDF writing, but it's pretty normal amongst Linux writers.
